# Can parallelization speed up FindClusters?

Tags: parallelization, implementation-details, cluster-analysis

I have a clustering task that would take `FindClusters` 2-3 months<sup>1</sup> to complete.

Can this calculation be sped up with parallelization?

(FWIW, the data to be clustered are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{14}$.  I'm calling `FindClusters` without any options (i.e. `FindClusters[mydata]`).  This means that the standard Euclidean metric is the measure of difference between data points.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This rough estimate is based on extrapolating the curve of execution times as a function of problem size for various subsamples of the full dataset.</sup>

Comment: Umm maybe Mathematica isn't the job for this...? And it's worth trying `Method` options to see if it speeds it up. And do you definitely not know the number of clusters beforehand?

Comment: @blochwave: regarding your last question: yes, definitely.

Comment: Your question is rather vague as it is--assuming the answer is yes, how do you propose to parallelize it? Considering that `FindClusters` is a kernel function (so you can't modify its code), this sounds like more of a theoretical proposition to me. Are you sure that the method used is the most efficient possible already before parallelization? If so, you may like to look for open-source libraries that implement that same method and consider modifying them to parallelize across a cluster (of computers).

Comment: @OleksandrR.: I should make clear that my question can be answered only by those who understand the algorithm used by `FindClusters` for the case described.  What I have in mind (as a *possibility*) is a strategy similar in spirit to that used by mergesort (independent sorts of subsets of the data that are subsequently combined).  It is conceivable that independent clusterings of subsets of the data can be subsequently "merged" into a global clustering.  Even some more information...

Comment: @OleksandrR.: ...about the algorithm that *Mathematica* uses for this case would help me carry out your suggestion to "look for open-source libraries that implement that *same method*"; the documentation for FindClusters is not specific enough for me to identify *Mathematica*'s method well enough to search for open source implementations thereof.

Comment: @kjo One of the algorithms (the default one) of `FindClusters` is [K-medoids / PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids).

Comment: @AntonAntonov: Thanks a bunch!  That information really helps.

Comment: @AntonAntonov: There's a wrinkle.  For the function [`FindClusters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html) apparently there are only two methods, `Agglomerate` and `Optimize` (the latter being the default for data like mine), but for the function [`ClusteringComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusteringComponents.html), there are *four* methods: `Agglomerate`, `Optimize`, `KMeans`, and `PAM`.  This gives me reason to think that `Optimize` may not be the same as `PAM` after all...